# Comparing TextView's getText() w/ R.string.stringValue in android?

Tags: android

Here's my code that's giving me grief.

```
TextView questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionView);
if(questionView.getText().equals(R.string.begginigStatement){
    currentQuestionIndex = -2;
    Log.d(TAG, "the TextView's text is equal to R.string.beggingStatement);
}
```

I'm trying to compare a string w/ an int
but I can't figure out the solution other than perhaps hardcoding the string, though I know that's not a proper convention. What's the solution?

Answer (score 5):

`R.string.begginigStatement` is just an ID of the string as generated in `R.class`. To retrieve the value call:

`getResources().getString(R.string.begginigStatement)`

Comment: Also EditText.getText() returns an Editable, not a String. Bryan also needs to use getString(). EditText.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.beginingStatement))

Answer (score 2):

try to use:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.begginigStatement);
```

and context can be 'getActivity()' if it's in Fragment or just :

```
getResources().getString(R.string.begginigStatement)
```

if it has context

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare this string values:

```
questionView.getText().toString().equal(getResources().getString(R.string.begginigStatement))
```